# How to get tagger url using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using Facebook's FQL to my website and call queries with the php-sdk api and i tried to find information about who tagged me in the photos i'm tagged. If you mouseOver a tag Name in fb then a frame appears with the tagged persons profile and on the top ot says 'Tagged by: '. I searched in FQL tables 'photo' and 'photo_tag' but that information is not to be found.

Is there an other table i should look for that information or is just one of the info fb keeps for themselves?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `photo_tag` and `video_tag` tables both have no info about the source/actor of the tag unfortunately.

Have a look at the `stream_tag` table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_tag/) if you're intereseted in Post tags.

You can then query for a user name like this:

```
select name from user where uid in (select actor_id from stream_tag where target_id = me())
```

Comment: This is very helpful! I missed that table and i came to a dead end. Does this query take under consideration all kinds of posts?